# navigaionController adds 1 uiview from that uiview pushViewController is not getting called

Tags: ipad, uiview, navigationcontroller

my application is having 3 different uiviewcontrollers say 1,2,3. I have added navigation controller to the application programatically.
from the 1st viewController i'm calling 2nd viewController by pushViewController.
from 2nd view controller i'm calling 3rd viewController by pushViewController.
on 3rd i'm adding 2nd view controller's view for half screen. again from that added view i'm trying to call 3rd viewCOntroller..but no luck.
Can anyone please help me in this??

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a [splitview controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW2).

Comment: Thank u for u reply, but spliviewcontroller does not suit to my requirement. My application is uiviewcontroller teplate app.

Comment: A splitview can be made programmatically if you wish (splitview template is less/more difficult for customizing) still if I am right you just need to create a new view with initWithFrame and add another navigation controller.